# Mistakenly remove reference of the whole project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift5, xcode10.3

I am working on an iOS project but mistakenly I just remove reference of the whole project in Xcode. After that, I have tried to add all of these folders and files but now the scheme is gone that's why I can't build the project anymore. Can we fix this horrible problem?

Comment: Restore the project from your version control system or backups, whichever is newer.

Comment: then the newest modification (today's work) will be lost.

Comment: I have able to import all files and folder but now I am facing codesign error. "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code"

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly work-around, but it has been known to work.

- Start a new project with the same name (just stored in a different place)
- Remove all the code from the project navigator, including the storyboard
- Import all the files and the storyboard from the original project.
- Double-check the storyboard (I had problems with loss of segue IDs)

It took time, but at least it made the codesign problem go away.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment but I am able to fix this horrible issue. I just created a new project and replace all controllers, image assets and storyboard. that's made the fix for me.

Comment: Good to hear! It sounds as if we both hit on a very similar solution. If you're willing, would you up-vote my response? Thanks